# Image POST Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make a POST from an Android image for an API. Please help me?

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
File file = new File( "/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20151116-WA0004.jpg" );
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/users/photo/");

MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("photo", file); <<== Error
entityBuilder.addTextBody("user", "98");

HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
post.setEntity(entity);
```

Error:

```
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: Process: br.com.bzum.myapplication, PID: 28282
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:146)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at br.com.bzum.app.api.Api.postPhoto(Api.java:74)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at br.com.bzum.app.api.ApiTaskPost.doInBackground(ApiTaskPost.java:23)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at br.com.bzum.app.api.ApiTaskPost.doInBackground(ApiTaskPost.java:9)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
11-23 09:27:22.874 28282-28441/br.com.bzum.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow should be in English.

Comment: you get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType` add the appropriate `jar` file.

Comment: Why use deprecated `HttpClient` and not one of the libraries which allow you to easily add multiparts?

Comment: I'm starting in Java! Which indicates library me ?

Comment: Volley, RetroFit, OkHttp, etc. These are popular ones. Google and see which one suits your needs.

Comment: Personal'm still with this problem ...
A please help!

Answer (score 0):

It helps you.

```
private Intent getShareIntent(String type, String subject)
{
    boolean found = false;
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/png");
    // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    System.out.println("resinfo: " + resInfo);
Uri phototUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/test.png");
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) ||
                    info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type) ) {
                share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/png");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                // Attach the PDf as a Uri, since Android can't take it as bytes yet.
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, phototUri);
                share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            return null;

        return share;
    }
return null;}
```

Comment: what would be the parameters above type and subject?
Which I pass the parameter I need user=98 ?

Comment: type is gmail, facebook, twitter etc. And subject is a message like "image is downloading.." .

Comment: if I have to pass a parameter of "user", "98" should go like this? 
Example : share.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "user", "98");

Comment: String message = "user" + "98" ;
(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, message);

Comment: Something that is understood on how I will spend a Intent with POST parameter... This solution above will suit me?

The need is to make this Curl only on my Android
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: multipart / form-data "-F" photo=@/Users/wcarvalho/image.jpg; type = image / gif "-F" user = 2 "http: // xx .xx.xxx.xxx / users / photo /

Comment: Personal'm still with this problem ...
A please help!